# Using min(x,y) in r returning 'subset' must be logical

Tags: r

I have a simple script that :

```
 min(125,456)
Error in subset.default(x, subset) : 'subset' must be logical
```

Which used to work fine as simple as it is. Since this morning is need to use base::min(125,456) to make it work. I assume this is because of some other package offseting/conflicting. How can i handle this so i do not have to apply "`base::`" to all the `{base}` functions of the code please?

```
> getAnywhere("min")
2 differing objects matching ‘min’ were found
in the following places
  package:rapportools
  package:base
  namespace:rapportools
  namespace:base
Use [] to view one of them
```

Comment: Looks like you've created a `min` function somewhere in your global environment and it is masking the `base::min` function in your interactive session.. Do `ls()` and see if `"min"` is there. Possibly it needs to be removed.

Comment: Hey, I haven't created a function with conflicting name, and ls() does not show any object with such name.

Comment: check with `getAnywhere("min")`, if the function is coming from some different package other than base.

Comment: @RonakShah, I just changed the question to add the getAnywhere command that you suggested

Comment: I did detach("package:rapportools", unload=TRUE) and it seems all ok now. but what if I need to use rapportools as well in some other part of the program ? Is there a right way to load things ? or base:: is the only option

Comment: you can keep `rapportools` detached and whenever you need any function from it, use `rapportools::function_name`.

Comment: Ok, which makes sense since I probably use base more often. I can validate your help somehow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see from `getAnywhere` command that `min` is being exported from package `rapportools`. Assuming we need only limited functions from `rapportools` package we can `detach` the package using

```
detach("package:rapportools", unload=TRUE)
```

and use `rapportools::function_name` wherever needed which will avoid masking the basic R functions and they can be applied without using `base::`.